# CSS image max-height doesn't keep aspect ratio

Tags: html, css

[Video preview](https://streamable.com/czwj3t)

I have a popup modal which has a fixed position with 100% width and height.

The content in the modal has `max-width: 90%;` and `max-height: 90%`

The image also has these values but the problem is that it doesn't keep the aspect ratio when changing the height, but has it when changing the width. (The video explains it all)

```css
#popup {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  opacity: 1;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.popupModal {
  max-width: 90%;
  max-height: 90%;
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, #fff, #f0f0f0);
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  transform: translateY(-100px);
  transition: transform 0.5s;
}

.closeBtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: -25px;
  right: -25px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #fff;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: $blue-dark;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 27px -10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.95);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 27px -10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.95);
  box-shadow: 0 0 27px -10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.95);
  transition: box-shadow 0.2s ease;
}

.closeLine {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: #072742;
  height: 4px;
  width: 50%;
}

#closeLineOne {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

#closeLineTwo {
  transform: rotate(135deg);
}

.closeLine:hover {
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.popupActive {
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 5000;
  transition: z-index 0s 0s, opacity 0.5s 0s;
}

.popupModal {
  transform: translateY(0);
}

.metalModal {
  height: 80%;
  background: transparent;
}

.metalPopup {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  // It works if I change the max-height to height, but it then stretches out all other images.
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.metalImg {
  max-width: 100%;
  flex: 1;
  object-fit: cover;
  max-height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
}

.metalName {
  width: 100%;
  height: 70px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  font-size: 24px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="popup" class="popupActive">
  <div class="popupModal metalModal">
    <div class="metalPopup">
      <div class="closeBtn">
        <span id="closeLineOne" class="closeLine"></span>
        <span id="closeLineTwo" class="closeLine"></span>
      </div>
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/BeWSEDB.jpg" class="metalImg" />
      <div class="metalName">
        Metal name
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT:**

The image keeps the aspect ratio when I give the `.metalPopup` class `display: block`. But it makes so that the width stays as the original `img` width, even though the image is a fraction of the whole block.

^ [See here](https://prnt.sc/117kuve).

Comment: Try specifying either `width` or `height` as `auto` and the other in `%`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I just changed `.metalPopup` max-height to just `height: 100%;` and it seems to work now and doesn't stretch the image, because the `.metalImg` now has max-height that removes the height of `.metalName` (Which is now `position: relative`, because it doesn't center the modal responsively if I want to, but can still be added to relative positioning and just subtract the height of it).

```css
#popup {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  opacity: 1;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.popupModal {
  max-width: 90%;
  max-height: 90%;
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, #fff, #f0f0f0);
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  transform: translateY(-100px);
  transition: transform 0.5s;
}

.closeBtn {
  position: relative;
  top: 25px;
  margin: 0 0 0 auto;
  right: -25px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #fff;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: $blue-dark;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 27px -10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.95);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 27px -10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.95);
  box-shadow: 0 0 27px -10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.95);
  transition: box-shadow 0.2s ease;
}

.closeLine {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: #072742;
  height: 4px;
  width: 50%;
}

#closeLineOne {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

#closeLineTwo {
  transform: rotate(135deg);
}

.closeLine:hover {
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.popupActive {
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 5000;
  transition: z-index 0s 0s, opacity 0.5s 0s;
}

.popupModal {
  transform: translateY(0);
}

.metalModal {
  height: 80%;
  background: transparent;
}

.metalPopup {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.metalImg {
  max-width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  max-height: calc(100% - 130px);
}

.metalName {
  width: 100%;
  height: 70px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  font-size: 24px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
}
```

```html
<div id="popup" class="popupActive">
  <div class="popupModal metalModal">
    <div class="metalPopup">
      <div class="closeBtn">
        <span id="closeLineOne" class="closeLine"></span>
        <span id="closeLineTwo" class="closeLine"></span>
      </div>
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/BeWSEDB.jpg" class="metalImg" />
      <div class="metalName">
        Metal name
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: There is, as they say, more than one way to skin the cat.  I like `object-fit: cover` in my CSS to achieve that effect.

Answer (score 2):

If you set height it's usually a good idea to make the width auto and vice versa.

```
.yourclass {
max-height: 90%;
max-width: (either unset or auto)
}
```

Comment: I usually follow this guideline, but since the question I've already added that to every single element that uses it.

Comment: would you mind updating the code here if it isn't? So I can play around with it and help you further

Comment: Yeah. Not much changed, because I was still hoping this would get answered. But this is the most up-to-date code I have.
I'm tinkering with it now.

Comment: ok all I changed for it to work is give .popupmodal max-width: 90%; max-height: auto;

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of **aspect-ratio** in CSS to maintain a specific ratio of the video.

```
video {
   width: 90%;
   aspect-ratio: 16/9 ; // due to this video will maintain aspect ratio of 16/9
}
```

this is almost supported by all modern browsers and will make you write less code.

Comment: The aspect-ratio is great but it's only for static images which have a specific aspect-ratio. In my case there's 50-60 images which all have completely different sizes.

Answer (score -1):

how about this. does it work for you?

```css
img {
  width: auto;  
  height: auto;  
  max-width:90%;
  max-height:90%;
}
```

Comment: It already has those values. Height is being rescaled according to width but not the other way around,